# Adding groovy nature to a java project

Tags: java, eclipse, groovy, junit, spock

I added groovy nature to my java project. My goal is to write Spock tests for my project. I'm using sts 3.6 and Grails. This messes up all my plain Junit test. Now I get a Classnotfoundexception everytime I run one. Also the compiler seems to be confused. It compiles groovy class as a java class. I understand that the problem is that my classes are not built but what I don't know is how to set up a compiler in a java/groovy project. A link, a help, a guide, a tutorial, an advice, all is welcome.

Comment: You should use Maven in your project. Add groovy support in Maven and then import this project in Eclipse. Changing your build via Eclipse is a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

See the Spock example for a complete project that does what you want https://github.com/spockframework/spock-example

It uses both Gradle and Maven for demonstration purposes, but you can select either in your real application.